# error:40 in VS2010 while try to access data from integrated Database

Tags: c#, sql

Please help me. i'm getting this error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Source Error:

```
Line 29:             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
Line 30:             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from SingUp", con);
Line 31:             con.Open();
Line 32:             using(con)
Line 33:             {
```

> Source File: C:\Users\My\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\myproject1\Asad\PostAvertisement.aspx.cs    Line: 31

Comment: Is your connection string `conStr` valid?

Answer (score 0):

*Well*, this problem may occure because of a few reasons. Since you didn't mentioned what have you tried already, you can follow this instructions;

> 1. Make sure your database engine is configured to accept remote connections
> 2. Check the SQL Server service account
> 3. If you are using a named SQL Server instance, make sure you are using that instance name in your connection strings in your ASP.NET
>      web application
>      4.You may need to create an exception on the firewall for the SQL Server instance and port you are using
> 4. If you are using a named SQL Server instance, make sure you are using that instance name in your connection strings
> 5. Check SQLBrowser; check that it is running. You may also need to create an exception in your firewall for SQLBrowser.
> 6. Check that you have connectivity to the SQL Server. Note what you are using to connect: machine name, domain name or IP address? Use
>      this when checking connectivity.

Source: http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server